# React - state for each variable vs as little state necessary

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, and booking system I'm making, I initially thought the best approach would be to separate out variables that change into separate pieces of state. For example, when a class is booked, the change the state of the calendar, but also the number of remaining classes should decrement by 1, like so:

```
function Calendar(){
    const [remainingClasses, setRemainingClasses] = useState(10);
    const [bookings, setBookings] = useState() // from API call that sets calendar timeslots

    const addBooking = () => {
        //add booking logic then:
        let newRemainingClasses = remainingClasses - 1;
        setRemainingClasses(newRemainingClasses);

        setBookings(newBookings);
    }
}
```

Essentially, I'm keeping each variable in its own state, even though I don't need to. I get the same result when I declare the `remainingClasses` variable outside of the function, as calling `setBookings` rerenders the component anyway.

```
let remainingClasses = 10;

function Calendar(){
    const [bookings, setBookings] = useState() // from API call that sets calendar timeslots

    const addBooking = () => {
        //add booking logic then:
        remainingClasses -= 1;

        setBookings(newBookings);
    }
}
```

So, is there any benefit of the former version / risk of the latter version messing up my code? Or is it best to use as little state as needed to make the application work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, is there any benefit of the former version / risk of the latter version messing up my code?

Yes. The former is per-instance state, so it'll be confined to each instance of `Calendar`. The latter is shared information across **all** `Calendar` instances, and isn't state information (changing it won't make your component re-render). There are various different approaches to keeping state information, but one thing you *don't* want to do is have it held outside the component entirely (well, unless it's provided to the component as props or context).

However, it doesn't seem (from that small example) that you need `remainingClasses` at all. Instead, perhaps a `maxClasses` constant, then calculate `remainingClasses` as and when you need it.

For instance, if you need it for every component render:

```
const maxClasses = 10;

function Calendar(){
    const [bookings, setBookings] = useState([]);
    const remainingClasses = maxClasses - bookings.length;

    // ...presumably a `useEffect` here or similar that does the API call
    // to load the bookings ...

    const addBooking = () => {
        // ...booking logic...
        setBookings(newBookings);
    };

     // ...
}
```